# Show either a set exists or prove cannot

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUhiq.png)

I believe this is not true because we will have an overlap somewhere since the max degree is 2 but we have 4 polynomials in the set.

How can I go about proving no linearly independent set exists though? Can I use dimension here?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

We have $ \dim P_2( \mathbb R) =3$, since $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is a basis of $P_2( \mathbb R)$.

Your turn !

Comment: Since dimension is 3, that is the maximum number of LI vectors allowed?

Comment: I'd say "possible" instead of "allowed" but I think you got the idea, yes!